# Granger Causality doesn't agree with VAR

Tags: time-series, t-test, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

I have 6 econometric price series (2 of which are of particular interest here - let's call them X1 and X2), for which I have tried to run the Granger Causality tests and cross-checked it with VAR.

While running Granger Causality Tests on X1,X2 - I see extremely strong significance at all lags (X1 explaining X2);
However, when I build VAR model, I am not seeing any of the lags of X1 figure out in X2 - i.e. the t-statistic is not high enough.

Is that even possible? If so, why?

I am using Python 3.0 statsmodels. 0.9.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an apples to oranges comparison.

1. You have two different models, a bivariate VAR for $X_1$ and $X_2$, call it **M2**, and a 6-variate VAR, call it **M6**.
2. You carry out a Granger causality test in the first case but look at significance of individual coefficients in the second case.

There is no reason for the results to necessarily coincide.

- Even if you fixed the model (say, **M2** in both cases), formal Granger causality testing need not always coincide with the informal look at individual coefficients. Granger causality test is an $F$-test, not a bunch of $t$-tests, unless the lag order of the VAR model is 1.
- Even if you fixed the test (say, you did the Granger causality test in both cases), you need not get the same result in **M2** as in **M6**. These are different models. Perhaps $X_1 \xrightarrow{\text{Granger}} X_2$ unconditionally but not conditionally on $X_3,X_4,X_5,X_6$ (just one possible example).

Comment: The wikipedia page of Granger causality notes this: "Multivariate Granger causality analysis is usually performed by fitting a vector autoregressive model (VAR) to the time series" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality#Multivariate_analysis

Comment: So, why is there absolutely no linkage between the two?

Comment: @Soham, between which two?

Comment: Between VAR and Granger Causality, given that multivariate GC is performed by fitting a VAR model, as the wiki page says

Comment: @Soham, VAR is a model while Granger causality is a type of statistical relationship between two or more time series. The linkage between the two is that VAR is typically used for implementing a test for Granger causality (though it has multiple other uses beyond that as well).